# Store view Price Extension Issue

Tags: magento2, store, price

I have installed an extension for store view pricing (https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-store-view-pricing).

The extension is working fine in admin side and single product page, but not working in category and Search page. Category page and Search Suggestions is showing only default price.

Anyone Help me to figure it out

I don't know how to acheive this. Support Required

Comment: This is a bug in this module and the issue is still active for nearly a year. https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-store-view-pricing/issues/3

Comment: any help here?. as My project is going to be live just this issue is causing the problem.